# What devices can I Airplay to?

Tags: airplay

With AirPlay will I be able to stream to iPhone, iPod Touch, and/or iTunes, or is it only to Apple TV and 3rd party speakers?

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/what-devices-can-receive-an-ios-airplay-audio-stream

Comment: No it's not exactly, that is about streaming to old Apple Tv I'm want to know about streaming **to** a Mac or iPhone

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to make that clearer and I'm reopening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Airplay is really a technology platform that allows for streaming media on a local network. It isn't concerned with the type of device that is producing the media or consuming it.

To start with, support may be limited and may not come from Apple. However, certainly that will change with demand. For example:

- There is an iOS app called [AirPlayer](http://www.edavs.com/AirPlayer.shtml) which allows streaming of media to an iPhone/iPod/iPad.
- There is a Mac proof-of-concept app also called [AirPlayer](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/12/14/hacksugar-mac-based-airplay-service-allows-device-to-mac-playba/) which allows streaming of media to a Mac.

Comment: Reading the AirPlayer link, that doesn't use Apple's AirPlay—it uses UPnP or DLNA. Hence, AirPlay devices such as the AppleTV *cannot* stream to the (unfortunately-named) AirPlayer iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Banana TV](http://bananatv.net/) is a currently shipping Mac app (not just a proof-of-concept) that will play Airplay video or images from your iPhone/iPad.

([TUAW review](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/21/banana-tv-now-shipping/))

Comment: Banana TV's site is now down

Answer (score 1):

[Airserver](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/airserver-connect/id967004087) allows you to stream Airplay audio and video from your iOS device to your Mac. Works great.

Comment: Locked to to a dispute about edits. Please add a comment if you see the need for a further edit and either mention me or flag for mod attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can Airplay **to** Windows, Mac, Android, or Amazon Fire using [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/win/). It claims to support sending rom iOS 9 devices also (but I personally haven't tested the iOS 9 support yet).

Reflector installs an app that acts as an AirPlay and Google Cast receiver. The app is available for Windows, Mac, Android, or Amazon Fire. Since Reflector supports receiving both AirPlay and Google Cast it can receive audio/video from iOS or Android.

It's from Squirrels, the same company that makes the excellent [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) app (which allows you send AirPlay audio and video **from** Windows and Mac **to** AirPlay and Google Cast).