# Is AppleTV the only device that can receive AirPlay VIDEO?

Tags: appletv, airplay

3rd-party AirPlay-enabled AV-receivers are starting to hit the market ([Pioneer](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Home/AV-Receivers/Pioneer+Receivers/VSX-1021-K), [Denon](http://usa.denon.com/us/Airplayus/index.html), [Marantz](http://airplayus.marantz.com/)), but as far as I can tell, they can stream AirPlay *audio only*.

[Apple's page for AirPlay](http://www.apple.com/itunes/airplay/) seems to imply the same thing. The only Apple pages that mention video streaming are the [AppleTV page](http://www.apple.com/appletv/#remote) and the [iOS 4.3 Update](http://www.apple.com/ios/) page, which don't make any mention of 3rd-party products.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/airplay-which-devices) mentions that other iOS devices and Macs can be enabled to receive AirPlay video streams through 3rd-party apps.

So are there any existing (or announced) 3rd-party hardware products that can do so? I'm particularly interested in AV receivers as I plan my next home theater upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't intend to answer my own question, but I found [this March 2011 Bloomberg article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-03-23/apple-is-said-to-weigh-expanding-airplay-for-streaming-video-on-devices.html):

> Apple Inc. (AAPL) is weighing an
>   expansion of its AirPlay audio service
>   to include streaming video from an
>   iPhone or iPad to television sets,
>   according to two people familiar with
>   the project.
>
> Under the plan, Apple would license
>   its AirPlay software to
>   consumer-electronics makers that could
>   use it in devices for streaming
>   movies, TV shows and other video
>   content, said the people, who asked to
>   remain anonymous because the plans
>   haven’t been made public. Apple now
>   only licenses AirPlay for streaming
>   audio. Devices that could be used for
>   video may be available this year, one
>   of the people said.

So apparently the answer is "not yet, but maybe in the future."

Comment: answeing your own questions is totally fine, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: And nine years later, Denon et all still don't have support for AirPlay video, nor support for Google's Cast, either.  Maybe the hardware requirements for decoding video just aren't worth the cost?  :-(

Answer (score 3):

XBMC can also act as an Airplay video receiver so that'll add practically any computer to the list, but as far as I know, they've reverse engineered the protocol, so there are no guarantees it'll continue to work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: Though not the original poster, I'll provide the link:  http://xbmc.org/  More information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC

Answer (score 1):

Boxee Box works with AirPlay. You can install Boxee software on many hardware platforms so if the native software can't play Airplay you can always try to change it to Boxee.

Answer (score 1):

You can Airplay **to** Amazon Fire, Windows, Mac, or Android devices using [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/win/). It claims to support sending **from** iOS 9 devices also (note I personally haven't tested the iOS 9 support yet).

Reflector installs an app that acts as an AirPlay and Google Cast receiver. The app is available for Windows, Mac, Android, or Amazon Fire. Since Reflector supports receiving both AirPlay and Google Cast it can receive audio/video from iOS or Android.

It's from Squirrels, the same company that makes the excellent [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) app (which allows you send AirPlay audio and video **from** Windows and Mac **to** AirPlay and Google Cast).

Answer (score 0):

These days, many TVs (such as from Samsung and LG) and Roku boxes can receive AirPlay video. I believe they also support HomeKit.

List of AirPlay-compatible TVs and Rokus: https://www.igeeksblog.com/airplay-2-supported-tvs/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).